# Download size under the "Downloads" tab vs "Delivery" tab in Google Play App Bundle Explorer, which one is actual user's download size?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

When I upload an app bundle aab into the Google Play console (under internal testing track at the moment), I can see the following two tabs from the App Bundle Explorer. The sizes shown under the "Downloads" tab (for the APKs) and the "Delivery" tab (for my app only the "base" module) are very different.

Which one is the actual download size for an end user? I'd assume it's the "Delivery download size", but from the Google Play Store link Google generates for the user to install the app, the app info displays the full APK size. Isn't that kind of misleading to the user since it's (much) larger than the actual download size for user's device?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, the size that end users download is the one shown as "Download size" in the *Delivery* section.

Google Play does not compress artifacts in the *Internal Testing* track, that's why you see a discrepancy in size. If you publish your artifact to any other track (e.g. a closed track), you should start seeing the "actual" download size in the Play Store.